# Диаграмма donut SVG. Как сделать анимацию закрашивания?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация

Долгое время вожусь с анимацией закрашивания круга в зависимости от процента. Необходимо реализовать такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент я смог реализовать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть все как надо, анимация закрашивания работает, но радиус синего круга очень маленький. На данный момент он составляет 69.85699, а необходимо 140. Когда я увеличиваю радиус - получается какая-то каша, то есть анимация начинается не с той же точки и заканчивается вот этим
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит, что при маленьком радиусе точка старта стоит на месте, а при большом она движется просто вокруг.

Вот код:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
        // var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
        // console.log(circle.getTotalLength());
        var time = 5; /* how long the timer will run (seconds) */
        var initialOffset = '440';
        var one_percent = initialOffset/100;
        var i = 0;

        $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('body').find(".statistics-left__donut-number").text(i);
            if (i == time) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            }
            $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
            i++;
        }, 1000);

    }, 0);
```

```css
svg{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.circle_animation{
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_dd)">
    <circle cx="160" cy="160" r="100" fill="#F5F8FD"/>
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#filter1_ii)">
    <mask id="a" fill="#fff">
      <path d="M320 160c0 88.366-71.634 160-160 160S0 248.366 0 160 71.634 0 160 0s160 71.634 160 160zm-280.003 0c0 66.276 53.727 120.003 120.003 120.003 66.276 0 120.003-53.727 120.003-120.003 0-66.276-53.727-120.003-120.003-120.003C93.724 39.997 39.997 93.724 39.997 160z"/>
    </mask>
    <path d="M320 160c0 88.366-71.634 160-160 160S0 248.366 0 160 71.634 0 160 0s160 71.634 160 160zm-280.003 0c0 66.276 53.727 120.003 120.003 120.003 66.276 0 120.003-53.727 120.003-120.003 0-66.276-53.727-120.003-120.003-120.003C93.724 39.997 39.997 93.724 39.997 160z" stroke="#E3E6EC" stroke-width="80" mask="url(#a)"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" cx="160" cy="160" r="140" stroke-width="40" stroke="#4277FF" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" data-percent="30"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_dd" x="22" y="22" width="276" height="276" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
      <feOffset dx="-18" dy="-18"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
      <feOffset dx="18" dy="18"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.819608 0 0 0 0 0.85098 0 0 0 0 0.901961 0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feBlend in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="effect2_dropShadow"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect2_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="filter1_ii" x="-20" y="-20" width="360" height="360" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
      <feOffset dx="-20" dy="-20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15"/>
      <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feBlend in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
      <feOffset dx="20" dy="20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15"/>
      <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.819608 0 0 0 0 0.85098 0 0 0 0 0.901961 0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feBlend in2="effect1_innerShadow" result="effect2_innerShadow"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

В JS скрипте, который отвечает за анимацию я пробовал увеличивать stroke-dashoffset, нашел как измерить длину круга (с помощью getTotalLength()) и подставил в переменную initialOffset - но получается еще хуже.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Почему радиус так меняет круг?

Загрузил на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robdev/d3kuvx1z/1/

Answer (score 2):

А можно так

```js
function start() {

  let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame ||
      mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      }
  })();

  let dataCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.progressbar__thumb');

  function setProgress(percent, selector) {
    let circle = selector.querySelector('.progressbar__thumb');
    let total = Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${total*percent/100} ${total*(1-percent/100)*2}`;
    selector.querySelector('text').innerHTML = '<tspan>' + percent.toFixed(0) + '</tspan>%';
  }

  function circle(final, i) {
    let number = -1;
    i++;
    let selector = '.progress__container:nth-child(' + i + ')';
    let mainSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
    let myReq = null;

    function circleStep() {
      myReq = reqAnimFrame(circleStep);
      setProgress(number, mainSelector);
      if (number >= final) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
      }
      number++;
    }
    circleStep();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dataCircle.length; i++) {
    let num = dataCircle[i].getAttribute('data-circle');
    circle(num, i);
  }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  start();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cards__progress__bar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress__container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ff0036;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transform-origin: center;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progressbar text {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.progressbar text tspan {
  fill: #ff0036;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards__progress__bar">

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="90" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="80" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="70" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- .progress__container -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, я забывал просто изменять в стилях dashoffset..